# GitVersion on Azure DevOps yaml pipeline fails on Linux

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, devops, gitversion

I am using GitVersion in Azure DevOps yaml pipeline. It works great on `windows-2022` agent but with `ubuntu-latest` or `ubuntu-20.04` the GitVersion step always fails with:

```
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet tool install GitVersion.Tool --tool-path /home/vsts/work/_temp --version 5.10.3
You can invoke the tool using the following command: dotnet-gitversion
Tool 'gitversion.tool' (version '5.10.3') was successfully installed.
Caching tool: GitVersion.Tool 5.10.3 x64
##[error]Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, readlink '/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet'
Finishing: GitVersion
```

The pipeline is pretty straight forward:

```yaml
pool:
  # vmImage: windows-2022
  vmImage: ubuntu-20.04

trigger:
- main

variables:
- name: buildConfiguration
  value: Release
- name: solutionFile
  value: src/mySolution.sln
- name: packagesToPush
  value: stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build, Pack and Push NuGet Package

  jobs:
  - job: BuildSolution
    displayName: Build Solution
    variables:
      GitVersion.SemVer: ""

    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: Use .NET 6
      inputs:
        version: 6.0.x

    - task: UseGitVersion@5
      displayName: GitVersion
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 5.x
        updateAssemblyInfo: false
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be the problem?

Comment: I replaced the task `- task: UseGitVersion@5` with:
```yaml
    - task: gitversion/setup@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 5.x

    - task: gitversion/execute@0
      inputs:
        updateAssemblyInfo: false
```
and it worked. But the question remains. Is there a bug in  UseGitVersion@5? Maybe it is time for UseGitVersion@6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested the same task and got the same issue.

> ##[error]Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, readlink '/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet'

The path: `/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet` is the value of the environment variable **Dotnet_Root**.

The expected value is `/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet`. This value is set in the task: **UseDotNet@2**.

The variable set in **UseDotNet@2** task is correct, but the task:**UseGitVersion@5** is using the wrong value of the **Dotnet_Root**(value:`/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet` ).

The issue indeed from the task itself.

To solve this issue, you can set the path in **UseDotNet@2**( `installationPath: ../share/dotnet`
).

Here is the YAML example:

```
pool:
  # vmImage: windows-2022
  vmImage:  ubuntu-latest

trigger:
- main

variables:
- name: buildConfiguration
  value: Release
- name: solutionFile
  value: src/mySolution.sln
- name: packagesToPush
  value: 
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build, Pack and Push NuGet Package

  jobs:
  - job: BuildSolution
    displayName: Build Solution
    variables:
      GitVersion.SemVer: ""

    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: Use .NET 6
      inputs:
        version: 6.0.x
        installationPath: ../share/dotnet
  
    - task: UseGitVersion@5
      displayName: GitVersion
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 5.x
        updateAssemblyInfo: false
```

Then it will work.

On the other hand, the task: UseGitVersion is deprecated. This means that the task will not update any more. Refer to this link: [GitVersion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gitversion&ssr=false#overview).

We suggest that you can change to use the extension: [GitTools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gittools) As you said in comment, it can work fine.

Comment: Great! Thank you. Upvoted and marked as the solution.